# Dynamically change background color based on text content

Tags: javascript

I have a column of GPA's I'd like to dynamically color based on the text content from 3.00 to 4.00. I'd like 3.00 to have a blue background and 4.00 to have a red background.

I've attempted document.querySelectorAll here, but it does not work?

```
var colorList = document.querySelector('.colorList');

colorList.style.backgroundColor = '#74abe5';

// This is just to demonstrate what color I'd like the highest cell to be.

var colorListEnd = document.querySelector('.colorListEnd');

colorListEnd.style.backgroundColor = '#d7727d'
```

http://jsbin.com/razicenari/edit?html,js,output

Visual representation of what I'm shooting for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ICIT.jpg

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```js
function convertRange( value, r1, r2 ) { 
    return ( value - r1[ 0 ] ) * ( r2[ 1 ] - r2[ 0 ] ) / ( r1[ 1 ] - r1[ 0 ] ) + r2[ 0 ];
}

var colorList = document.querySelectorAll('.colorList');

colorList.forEach(function(color){
  var colorPicker = convertRange(color.innerText, [3.0, 4.0], [50, 200]);
  color.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + Math.floor(colorPicker) + ",20," + Math.floor(255 - colorPicker) + ")";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>

        <th>GPA** <br> 50%
        </th>
        <th>75%</th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>SAT Reading*** <br>25%-75%</th>
        <th>SAT Math*** <br>25%-75%</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="colorList">3.52</td>
        <td>3.80</td>
        <td>4.00</td>
        <td>400-510</td>
        <td>400-530</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="colorList">3.62</td>
        <td>3.80</td>
        <td>4.00</td>
        <td>400-510</td>
        <td>400-530</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="colorList">3.72</td>
        <td>3.80</td>
        <td>4.00</td>
        <td>400-510</td>
        <td>400-530</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="colorList">3.82</td>
        <td>3.80</td>
        <td>4.00</td>
        <td>400-510</td>
        <td>400-530</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="colorList">3.92</td>
        <td>3.80</td>
        <td>4.00</td>
        <td>400-510</td>
        <td>400-530</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
var colorLists = document.querySelectorAll('.colorList');
for (let colorList of colorLists) {
    let value = Number(colorList.textContent),
        t = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, value - 3)),
        r = 116 * (1 - t) + 215 * t,
        g = 171 * (1 - t) + 114 * t,
        b = 229 * (1 - t) + 125 * t;

    colorList.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + (r | 0) + "," + (g | 0) + "," + (b | 0) + ")";
}
```

Comment: Yo can also iterate the arrays with `forEach`.

Comment: I've made an edit to give a better idea what I'm asking.